# SSRS How to make scope lookup dynamically? using parameters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

The custom code nested in report properties :

```
Function SumLookup(ByVal items As Object()) As Decimal  
If items Is Nothing Then  
Return Nothing  
End If  
Dim suma As Decimal = New Decimal()  
Dim ct as Integer = New Integer()  
suma = 0  
ct = 0  
For Each item As Object In items  
suma += Convert.ToDecimal(item)  
ct += 1  
Next  
If (ct = 0) Then return 0 else return suma   
End Function
```

My command like this :

```
=Code.SumLookup(LookupSet("9040101", Fields!norek.Value,Fields!tgl10.Value, "NR_01"))
```

If I run that command the result is not error. the value will be 100

Than

I just want to make `scope :"NR_01"` dynamically change when the parameters also change, I use `Parameters!nm_tabel.Value`. so I changed:

from `scope dataset: "NR_01"` to `scope :"Parameters!nm_tabel.Value"`

Become this

`=Code.SumLookup(LookupSet("9040101", Fields!norek.Value,Fields!tgl10.Value, "Parameters!nm_tabel.Value"))`

But I found an error `"... The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox12.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for a lookup function. The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is the name of a dataset..."`

How can I convert parameters to fit the requirement from that scope ?

Thanks Best Regardz

Comment: I have tried to convert to string the scope dataset become `=Code.SumLookup(LookupSet("1040101", Fields!nosbb.Value, Fields("tgl" & Parameters!nm_kolom.Value).Value, Trim(Parameters!nm_tabel) ))`. but still Error

Comment: try without the " around the Parameters!nm_kolom.Value otherwise you are turning it into a string rather than getting the value